# How to add dynamically data in form through ajax in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got data from db through an `ajax` call and tried to add it in forms's input `tags`.
When I add data in the form dynamically through `Ajax`, the webpage gets stuck and a black layer is coming on the webpage, and I can't do anything.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "post",
  data: mydata,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == 1) {
      let is_free = data.value['is_free'];
      console.log(typeof data.value['is_free']);
      
      document.getElementById("id_Lecture_Title").value = (data.value['title']);
      document.getElementById("lec_desc").value = (data.value['desc']);
      document.getElementById("free_preview_lec").checked = true;

      $("#add_lecture_model").modal("show");
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Ttn.png)

Comment: Does it perform the post alright if you comment out the success function?

Comment: maybe the `$("#add_lecture_model").modal("show");` triggers that opacity layer you observed? did you check with the network activity inside the developer tools? if the request actually was completed and return 200? did you try to put some console.log calls in some specific point to understand exactly where things get stuck?